# Как filter() и reduce() работают изнутри?

Tags: python

Про zip и map я нашёл. Но вот как работают изнутри эти 2 - без понятия.
В идеале хотел бы увидеть примерный код, ну или псевдокод

Comment: Вам что-то мешает посмотреть [реализацию](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py#L476)?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev До вашего комментария - мешало то, что я не знаю где её искать

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, написал бы в ответе что ли (вместе  кодом).

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, обновил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

filter

```
def _filter(func, iterable):
    for el in iterable:
        if func(el):
            yield el
```

reduce (tnx @insolor)

```
def _reduce(func, iterable):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    value = next(iterable)
    for element in iterable:
        value = func(value, element)
    return value
```

реализация в functools 
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py#L476

Comment: @insolor Да, просмотрел

Comment: Начальное значение из самой последовательности можно взять, вот так можно реализовать: https://ideone.com/1ne30d

Comment: Реализация `reduce` на питоне описана в документации: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce